# Internal Exception: string indices must be integers

Tags: jaseci

jaseci > walker run test_train_ner
2022-11-11 14:26:09,593 - ERROR - rt_error: ent_ext.jac:test_train_ner - line 30, col 25 - rule expr_list - Internal Exception: string indices must be integers
{
"success": false,
"stack_trace": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\interp.py", line 829, in run_atom_trailer\n    ret = atom_res.value.trigger(param_list, self.*jac_scope, self)\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\attr\action.py", line 64, in trigger\n    result = func(*param_list)\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci_ai_kit\modules\ent_ext\ent_ext.py", line 325, in train\n    create_train_data(val_data, "val")\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci_ai_kit\modules\ent_ext\ent_ext.py", line 126, in create_train_data\n    for ent in t_data["entities"]:\nTypeError: string indices must be integers\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\actor\walker.py", line 168, in run\n    while self.step() and not self.yielded:\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\actor\walker.py", line 87, in step\n    self.run_walker(jac_ast=self.get_architype().get_jac_ast())\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\walker_interp.py", line 25, in run_walker\n    self.scope_and_run(\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\walker_interp.py", line 267, in scope_and_run\n    run_func(jac_ast)\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\walker_interp.py", line 53, in run_walker_block\n    self.run_statement(i)\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\interp.py", line 205, in run_statement\n    self.run_rule(kid[0])\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\interp.py", line 1745, in run_rule\n    val = getattr(self, f"run*{jac_ast.name}")(jac_ast, *args)\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\interp.py", line 442, in run_report_action\n
self.run_expression(kid[1])\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\interp.py", line 480, in run_expression\n    self.jac_try_exception(e, jac_ast)\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\machine\machine_state.py", line 189, in jac_try_exception\n    raise e\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\interp.py", line 457, in run_expression\n    self.push(self.run_rule(kid[0]))\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\interp.py", line 1745, in run_rule\n    val = getattr(self, f"run_{jac_ast.name}")(jac_ast, *args)\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\interp.py", line 781, in run_atom\n    self.jac_try_exception(e, jac_ast)\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\machine\machine_state.py", line 189, in jac_try_exception\n    raise e\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\interp.py", line 764, in run_atom\n    ret = self.run_atom_trailer(i, ret)\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\interpreter\interp.py", line 844, in run_atom_trailer\n    self.jac_try_exception(e, jac_ast)\n  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\jaseci\jac\machine\machine_state.py", line 191, in jac_try_exception\n    raise TryException(self.jac_exception(e, jac_ast))\njaseci.jac.machine.machine_state.TryException: string indices must be integers\n",
"report": [],
"final_node": "urn:uuid:cbd55e11-6d42-4a28-8539-27a0780caa49",
"yielded": false,
"errors": [
"ent_ext.jac:test_train_ner - line 30, col 25 - rule expr_list - Internal Exception: string indices must be integers"
]
}

```
walker test_train_ner{
can ent_ext.train;
train_data=[
    {
        "context": "EU rejects German call to boycott British lamb",
        "entities": [
            {
                "entity_value": "EU",
                "entity_type": "ORG",
                "start_index": 0,
                "end_index": 2
            },
            {
                "entity_value": "German",
                "entity_type": "MISC",
                "start_index": 11,
                "end_index": 17
            },
            {
                "entity_value": "British",
                "entity_type": "MISC",
                "start_index": 34,
                "end_index": 41
            }
        ]
    }
];
train_params={"num_epoch": 2, "batch_size": 1, "LR": 0.02};
report ent_ext.train(train_data=train_data,train_params=train_params);
```

}

The error is happening because of train param variable, please help to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is perhaps the call to

```
report ent_ext.train(train_data=train_data,train_params=train_params);
```

Jac currently doesn't support keyword argument in action calls and supports the C-style argument list as per

```
ent_ext.train(train_data,train_params);
```

I believe keyword arguments is on the roadmap.